# How to write query to get count occurences of events of different types?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named EventHistory which has fields as shown in the table. A and B together constitutes primary key for the table. For every ke, I want to calculate how many events are of schedule and manual_schedule and displays its count and how many are of cancel type in seperate columns for particular key?

Sample Data:

```
  A        B                 createdAt         createdBy  eventType  
249106  1956901101  2020-01-24 12:01:21.8300000 MOC000  manual_schedule
249106  1956901101  2019-12-11 04:44:42.0000000 VSSUBR  schedule
249106  1956901101  2019-12-10 13:12:32.6980000 VSSUBR  cancel
249128  1956904001  2020-01-27 10:14:23.8930000 MOC000  manual_schedule
249128  1956904001  2020-01-23 09:45:20.7450000 MOC000  manual_schedule
249128  1956904001  2019-12-17 08:41:25.0000000 VSSUBR  schedule
249128  1956904001  2019-11-28 11:46:40.4930000 VSSUBR  hold
249128  1956904001  2019-11-28 11:46:15.8160000 VSSUBR  cancel
249240  1956932501  2020-01-06 10:44:46.7620000 YUG000  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2020-01-02 21:09:05.0000000 A9SRI3  schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-31 06:41:01.3300000 KRSRIP  cancel
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 08:35:35.7490000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 08:30:09.0000000 External    reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:56:31.0000000 VSSUBR  reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:55:03.8030000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:16:04.0000000 VSSUBR  reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:14:46.9600000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:14:43.0000000 VSSUBR  reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:13:21.2890000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-17 05:11:51.5050000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-13 10:02:49.7800000 KRSRIP  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-13 10:02:49.7760000 KRSRIP  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-12 04:20:04.1620000 VSSUBR  cancel
249240  1956932501  2019-12-05 12:30:42.2630000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-05 12:23:52.3480000 VSSUBR  manual_schedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-05 09:49:37.0000000 External    reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-05 09:48:42.0000000 External    reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-04 13:16:10.0000000 External    reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-04 12:59:00.0000000 External    reschedule
249240  1956932501  2019-12-04 07:29:43.0000000 External    schedule
```

Comment: Guessing your design (as we have no sample data), but i would suggest you are after a `PIVOT` or conditional aggregate. What have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I haven't write query. I have given the table and I have to query for same. I have to group by firstName, lastName fields and also count occurrences of different events. In example, I'm assuming that eventType="goToGym" occurs 10 times for Shreyak Jain and eventType="goToMovie" occurs 2 times in table for Shreyak Jain. So, outputting same. This is my desired output.

Comment: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @EricBrandt sure will add same

Comment: So why haven't you tried? If you haven't tried, what about the examples you've looked at when you researched this what, did you find and what about them didn't you understand about them? Was said solution(s) using `PIVOT` or conditional aggregation?

Comment: @Larnu actually i didn't know about pivot. Will read about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need conditional aggregation here. I typically do this with CASE statements. The select statement at the bottom demonstrates how I do this with a subset of your example data.

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #TEMP
    
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
        A                       INT
        ,B                      INT
        ,event_type             NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    INSERT INTO #TEMP (A,B,event_type)
    VALUES 
         ('249106','1956901101','manual_schedule')
        ,('249106','1956901101','schedule')
        ,('249106','1956901101','manual_schedule')
        ,('249128','1956904001','manual_schedule')
        ,('249128','1956904001','schedule')
        ,('249128','1956904001','manual_schedule')
        ,('249128','1956904001','manual_schedule')
        ,('249128','1956904001','schedule')
        ,('249240','1956932501','manual_schedule')
        ,('249240','1956932501','schedule')        
    
    SELECT A
        ,B
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'manual_schedule' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [manual_schedule]
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN event_type = 'schedule' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [schedule]
    FROM #TEMP
    GROUP BY A
        ,B
```

SAMPLE DATA OUTPUT AND SELECT STATEMENT OUTPUT:
[image]